# django form failed to get values from request

Tags: django, django-forms

this is views.py

```
def registerItem(request):
    print(request)
    try:
        print("====111", request.method)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("=========222", request.POST)
            form = ItemForm(request.POST)
            print("====333", form.is_bound)
            print("====444", form)
            print("====555", form.cleaned_data['mart_id']())
            print("====666", form.is_valid())
            if form.is_valid():
                mart = MartModel.objects.get(id__exact=form.cleaned_data['mart_id'])
                print("====666", mart)
                seq = ItemModel.objects.filter(mart_id__exact=mart).values('seq').order_by('-seq')[:1]
                if seq:
                    seq = seq[0]['seq']+1
                else:
                    seq = 1
                # form.save()
                item = ItemModel(mart_id=mart, seq=seq, name=form.cleaned_data['name'], price=form.cleaned_data['price'], expirationDate=form.cleaned_data['expirationDate'], stockYn=form.cleaned_data['stockYn'])
                item.save()
                form = ItemForm()
                return render(request, 'mobileWeb/admin/register_item.html', {'form':form})
        else:
            form = ItemForm()
            return render(request, 'mobileWeb/admin/register_item.html', {'form':form})
    except Exception as ex:
        print('====777 : Error occured : ', ex)
```

request.POST value is correct. you can confirm it by log No.2.
form is bound correctly. you can confirm it by log No.3.
but the form failed to receive values. you can confirm it by log No.4.

[image]

this is forms.py

```
class MartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MartModel
        fields = ['name', 'address', 'tell', 'phone', 'xPosition', 'yPosition']

class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    choicesQueryset = MartModel.objects.all().values('id', 'name')
    choicesDic = []
    for choice in choicesQueryset:
        choicesDic.append((choice['id'], choice['name']))
    mart_id = forms.CharField(label='mart', widget=forms.Select(choices=choicesDic))
    class Meta:
        model = ItemModel
        fields = ['mart_id', 'name', 'price', 'expirationDate', 'stockYn']
```

this is models.py

```
class MartModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    address = models.TextField(blank=False)
    tell = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=12)
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=11)
    imageFileNo = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=3)
    xPosition = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    yPosition = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    delete_yn = models.CharField(blank=False, default="N", max_length=1)
    ins_dttm = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now_add=True)
    ins_user = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=20, default='ADMIN')
    upt_dttm = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now=True)
    upt_user = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=20, default='ADMIN')

class ItemModel(models.Model):
    mart_id = models.ForeignKey('martModel', models.DO_NOTHING)
    seq = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    expirationDate = models.DateField(blank=False)
    stockYn = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=1, default='Y')
    delete_yn = models.CharField(blank=False, default="N", max_length=1)
    ins_dttm = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now_add=True)
    ins_user = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=20, default='ADMIN')
    upt_dttm = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now=True)
    upt_user = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=20, default='ADMIN')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('mart_id', 'seq')
        )
```

I know about that it must be a instance not a value when deal with the foreignKey.
but the error occured on binding time.
is this concerend with foreignKey??

================
after advice

[image]

no mart name is here.

this is forms.py

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mart = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MartModel.objects.all(), to_field_name='name')
    class Meta:
        model = ItemModel
        fields = ['mart', 'name', 'price', 'expirationDate', 'stockYn']
```

this is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    try:
        marts = MartModel.objects.all().values('id', 'name', 'imageFileNo', 'xPosition', 'yPosition')
        items = ItemModel.objects.filter(stockYn__exact='Y').values('mart', 'name', 'price', 'expirationDate').order_by('mart_id', 'seq')

        return render(request, 'mobileWeb/index/index.html', {'marts':marts, 'items':items})
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Error occured : ', ex)

def registerMart(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST' :
            form = MartForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return render(request, 'mobileWeb/index/index.html')
        else :
            form = MartForm()
            return render(request, 'mobileWeb/admin/register_mart.html', {'form':form})
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Error occured : ', ex)

def registerItem(request):
    print(request)
    try:
        print("====111", request.method)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("=========222", request.POST)
            form = ItemForm(request.POST)
            print("====333", form.is_bound)
            print("====444", form)
            if form.is_valid():
                mart = MartModel.objects.get(id__exact=form.cleaned_data['mart'])
                print("====666", mart)
                seq = ItemModel.objects.filter(mart__exact=mart).values('seq').order_by('-seq')[:1]
                if seq:
                    seq = seq[0]['seq']+1
                else:
                    seq = 1
                # form.save()
                item = ItemModel(mart=mart, seq=seq, name=form.cleaned_data['name'], price=form.cleaned_data['price'], expirationDate=form.cleaned_data['expirationDate'], stockYn=form.cleaned_data['stockYn'])
                item.save()
                form = ItemForm()
                return render(request, 'mobileWeb/admin/register_item.html', {'form':form})
        else:
            form = ItemForm()
            return render(request, 'mobileWeb/admin/register_item.html', {'form':form})
    except Exception as ex:
        print('====777 : Error occured : ', ex)
```

this is debug variable when make Item Form
[image]

this is debug variable about queryset
[image]

this is debug variable about 1st member of queryset
[image]

ofcourse I did makemigrations, migrate.

Comment: You are trying to assign an integer to `mart_id` on your ItemModel. You could avoid this problem by following the Django convention of naming foreign key fields without an `_id` sufffix. Change the `mart_id` field on `ItemModel` to `mart` and you won't have this problem. You may have other problems because it looks like you are trying to do some unusual stuff. You might benefit from doing some basic Django forms tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why are you trying to approach like this. ModelForm has very nice way to handle FK, and if you want to show `name` of the MartModel object, then you can use [**`ModelChoiceField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)'s `to_field_name` option. For example:

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mart_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MartModel.objects.all(), to_field_name='name')
    class Meta:
        model = ItemModel
        fields = ['mart_id', 'name', 'price', 'expirationDate', 'stockYn']
```

Also, please change the name of the field `mart_id` to `mart`, because underneath django creates a field name `mart_id`, if you assign the field name to `mart`.

Finally, in the view, you should not call `cleaned_data[...]` before calling `form.is_valid()`. Unless the form is validated, the data won't be available in `cleaned_data`.

---

### Update

(from comments) Add a `__str__` method at the bottom of `MartModel` class:

```
class MartModel(models.Model):
   ...
   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Comment: I'm trying to your comment. but failed. why ModelChoiceField does not work appropriately? I apply all of your advice, and the result is like this

Comment: I edit the main content after your advice. could you help me one more time?

Comment: oh I'm sorry. the problem is not about an error. at the dropdown select list, I want to get the name of mart. but at template(html file) it seems returning marts instance. I check the reason by debuging. at debug time it returns the name of mart correctly. so I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Jin-hyeongMa can you try the updated answer please?

Comment: it works well. thank you. thank you very much.I wish you all the very best!